# Can I get the type of class from with in it?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a base class that can determine its own type, but I'm not sure how to go, obviously this.GetType doesn't work inside of a typeOf,  so is there any way to get the class type for the current class?

```
class BassClass {
public string GetValueofSomething() {
    Type type = typeof(this.GetType()); //this obviously doesn't work
    type = typeOf(BaseClass);  //works fine
    MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers();
    //Other stuff here
    return ""
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetType()` returns a `Type`, so no need for `typeof`:

```
class BassClass
{
     public string GetValueOfSomething()
     {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers();
        ...
    }
}
```

---

But you should really avoid accessing a derived classes's members with reflection, is possible. Declare an abstract or virtual member that derived classes can override:

```
class BaseClass
{
     protected virtual string Something
     {
         get { return ""; }
     }

     public string GetValueOfSomething()
     {
         return this.Something;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Type type = this.GetType();
MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers();
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `typeof`:

```
Type type = this.GetType();   //gets the actual type of this object
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the different usages of the `typeof` operator vs. the `System.Object.GetType` method:

### `obj.GetType()`

`GetType` is called on an object instance `obj` and returns that object's dynamic (runtime) type. (You could think of this being resolved only at runtime.)

### `typeof(T)`

The `typeof` operator is used on a type name `T`. (You could think of this as being resolved already at compile-time.)

---

You only ever need one of these two; you never need to combine `typeof` and `GetType`. So, in your case, simply `Type type = this.GetType();` should work just fine.